# can one customise the just audio package to include a resume function or is it included and i just don't know it

Tags: flutter, dart, android-developer-api

i am using the just audio package and i am unable to save the duration when audio is paused to make it that when i come back to the app it resumes play from where it had been paused. Then have a stop function to get rid of the duration.
my current code looks like this.

```
 child: IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if (_isplaying) {
                              widget.audioPlayer.pause();
                            } else {
                              widget.audioPlayer.play();
                            }
                            _isplaying = !_isplaying;
                          });
                        },
                        icon: Icon(
                          _isplaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow_rounded,
                          size: 40,
                          
                        ),
                      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

After pausing, you can get the current position of the player using `widget.audioPlayer.position`. This will return a `Duration` object and you can store it wherever you want. Next time, if you want to continue playing from this duration, you can use `widget.audioPlayer..seek(duration)..play()`

This will play the audio from the desired duration.

Hope this helps.